# DOT Product in pyspark?

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, dot-product

I have:

df1

```
+------------------+----------+
|               var|multiplier|
+------------------+----------+
|              var1|         1|
|              var2|         2|
|              var3|         3|
+------------------+----------+
```

df2

```
+-------+----------+-----+-----+----------+---------+
|   varA|      varB| varC| var1|      var2|     var3|
+-------+----------+-----+-----+--------------------+
|   abcd|       at1|    5|    1|        45|       12|
|   xyzw|       vt1|    7|    1|        23|       17|
+-------+----------+-----------+----------+---------+
```

Result:
df3

```
+-------+----------+-----+-----+----------+---------+---------------+
|   varA|      varB| varC| var1|      var2|     var3|     sumproduct|
+-------+----------+-----+-----+--------------------+---------------+
|   abcd|       at1|    5|    1|        90|       36|            127|
|   xyzw|       vt1|    7|    1|        46|       51|             98|
+-------+----------+-----------+----------+---------+---------------+
```

In python, I am able to achieve this by:

```
df1 = df1.set_index(['var'])
df3 = df2.dot(df1)
```

Any help on a similar pyspark way to do the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lst=df1.select("multiplier").rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()#put multiplier into a list
df3 =(
 df2.withColumn('a1', array('var1',      'var2',     'var3'))#Create an array from df2
 .withColumn('a2', array([F.lit(x) for x in lst]))#Insert array from df1
 .withColumn('a1',expr("transform(a1, (x,i)->a2[i]*x)"))#Compute dot product
 .select('varA','varB','varC','a1', *[F.col('a1')[i].alias(f'var{str(i+1)}') for i in range(3)])#Expand a1 back to original var columns
 .select('*', expr("aggregate(a1,cast(0 as bigint), (x,i) -> x+i)").alias('sumproduct'))#sumproduct
 .drop('a1','a2')
 )
```

df3.show()

```
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----------+
|varA|varB|varC|var1|var2|var3|sumproduct|
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----------+
|abcd| at1|   5|   1|  90|  36|       127|
|xyzw| vt1|   7|   1|  46|  51|        98|
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----------+
```

Remember if all you need is the dot product, udf is a possibility. We can use numpy which is very good at such stuff

```
import numpy as np
lst=df1.select("multiplier").rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()
dot_array = udf(lambda x,y: int(np.dot(x,y)), IntegerType())
df2.withColumn("dotproduct",dot_array(array('var1',      'var2',     'var3'),array([F.lit(x) for x in lst]))).show()

+----+----+----+----+----+----+----------+
|varA|varB|varC|var1|var2|var3|dotproduct|
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----------+
|abcd| at1|   5|   1|  45|  12|       127|
|xyzw| vt1|   7|   1|  23|  17|        98|
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----------+
```

Comment: Thanks. I added ```from pyspark.sql.types import FloatType, IntegerType``` to the beginning. Also, at line 4, i m agetting the following traceback:
```
PipelinedRDD object is not iterable
Traceback (most recent call last):
TypeError: 'PipelinedRDD' object is not iterable
```
I tried to modify that to :
```df2 = df2.withColumn("dotproduct",dot_array(array('var1','var2','var3'),array(lst.map(lambda x: F.lit(x)))))```

without luck. Any pointers why that may be happening?

Comment: Well figured that my collect() is not working at line 2. 
An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe. Because of that it cant iterate over lst since its an RDD. Got to solve that problem now. Never comes easy!

Comment: How can I help? I gave two solutions, which is problematic? Seem not to be able to understand what your issue is. remember collect can be quite expensive if the df is large. The rationale here is to get `multiplier` column broadcast in df2 for you to dot product. Based on the info you gave, my solutions should work.

Comment: Yes your solution is good. The problem is that since i cannot collect() the 'lst' RDD (probably something to do with my JAVA installs), I cant iterate over it in line 4. So I am trying to solve that problem. I tried exploring toLocalIterator() as ```lst = df1.select("multiplier").rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).toLocalIterator()``` but that doesn't work either. Anyway, I accepted your solution.